# Changing IBM WebSphere Message Broker node properties

Tags: java, messagebroker

I use com.ibm.mq.jar library to get access to IBM WMB node properties. Method `getProperties()` in `com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.MessageFlowProxy.Node` allows me to read all node's properties(for example `queueName : "qin"`). But i can't find method for setting/saving that properties. Is it possible to set properties and save them on WMB with the help of this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set the properties, they are "baked-in" to the xml which is sent to the DFE at deploy time.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the only way to change properties is to redeploy the flow. And can you give some more information about how to change properties in this way? Is this XML is in the .bar file? Do you know it's filename?

Comment: I found that file called broker.xml in .bar file. This file is deployment descriptor for WMB. I think it will be possible to edit broker.xml to change some properties and redeploy .bar remotly, but there is a question : is .bar recompilation needed when node's properties have been changed?

Comment: the abr itself is just a zip file so after changes you can simply rezip, however a better way is to look into the mqsiapplybaroverride command which is specifically created for altering property values when moving a bar between different environments